# How to create tabs on the button, and a setting page?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is a bit difficult to explain, so I'll try to give a simple example to what I'd want to implement.

A. When the menu button is pressed in the Market app there are some kind of tabs on the buttom, how can I implement this ?

B.now press the settings (after you press the menu button in the Market app),
Is there a way to create this kind of a layout or I have to start from scratch (I would really appreciate code example for this if there is no 'easy' way to do this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are referring to here is not a layout. This is the standard way of creating *menues* in Android applications.

Have a look at the following topic in the Android developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

And regarding your second question: for settings/preferences, you can use a PreferenceScreen/PreferenceActivity. This is shown pretty well here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

If, by tabs you mean the buttons that pop up after clicking menu, you will have create your own options menu.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

EDIT: For B, check out the PreferenceScreen/PreferenceActivity, as mention in an answer to this post. Just updating here with link for convinience.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Comment: about B : I noticed that this layout is basically the same in many apps and in more places like the messages settings...must be some kind of a template for this or something

Comment: No, you do not have to start from scratch. The PreferenceScreen/PreferenceActivity makes this kind of task pretty easy.